# Using java javax.inject.Provider with Spring @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inject

Can someone please explain, does it make sense to combine Provider with SCOPE_PROTOTYPE. Since, each time SocketSender gets injected I will get a new SocketSender object due to SCOPE_PROTOTYPE? It seems like it is pointless to combine these two. Please see the code below.   Is there any difference between these two implementation in any wise? Thanks in advance.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
  public SocketSender getSender() {
        return new SocketSender();
  }
}


//First implementation
class MyServiceImpl{
   private Provider<SocketSender> socketSender;

   @Inject
   public MyServiceImpl(Provider<SocketSender> socketSender){
     this.socketSender=socketSender;
   }

   public void doSomething(){
      socketSender.get().doAnotherThing();
   }  
}


//Second implementation
class MyServiceImpl{
private SocketSender socketSender;

@Inject 
public MyServiceImpl(SocketSender socketSender){
   this.socketSender=socketSender;
}

  public void doSomething(){
    socketSender.doAnotherThing();
  }  
}
```

Comment: Each time you call `get` on the `Provider` you will get a new instance (so for each method call). If you don't you will get the same instance each time.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it depends on what you what, sometime using `Provider` is a good choice sometimes it isn't.

For example, if you have some class `MyService` that needs a bean called, `MyBuilder` that should be created for each invocation of `foo` method (because it holds the state internally) then it makes sense to use prototype scope for `MyBuilder` and singleton scope for `MyService`.

If we use the straightforward implementation:

```
// singleton bean
class MyService  {

    // defined as a prototype in spring, but what about injection?
    @Autowired
    private MyBuilder myBuilder;

    public void foo(int param) {
      Product p = myBuilder.withParam(param).build();
      ... 
    }
}
```

If won't work as expected: The `myBuilder` object will be reused it will always be the same object...
It happens because Spring injects prototype into singleton only once, when the singleton gets initialized, and since than its always the same reference.

In order to solve this, you can use the `Provider`:

```
class MyService {

    private Provider<MyBuilder> myBuilder;

    public void foo(int param) {
         Product p = myBuilder.get().withParam(param).build();
         ...
    }
}
```

Now different invocations of `foo` method will work with different instances of `myBuilder`.